# External Jar not working "Could not autowire"

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, autowired, artifact

In IntelliJ IDEA, I am getting the following error:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'ExternalClass' type found.
>   Inspection info: Checks autowiring problems in a bean class

Background: I extracted a part of the code, and uploaded it as an artifact, when I tried to use it in my "main" code I got the error, and I'm unable to compile with maven.

```
@Autowired
public ClassName (ExternalClass externalClass){
   this.externalClass = externalClass;
}
```

The artifact is a dependency in the POM file, and it shows up fine on autocomplete.

I have tried with several classes, and the error comes every time.

Comment: Please add information and an [mcve] so that others are able to reproduce the issue. The only code you posted is - of course - totally fine in Spring context.

Comment: Can you post your complete code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue eventually and is sharing in case someone else gets the same error.
For autowire and spring to work properly, the artifact needed the same package structure as the main project.
Example:
if main project package structure is:

```
com.domainname.something.myproject
```

The artifact should be:

```
com.domainname.something.myproject.artifactname
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a `@Configuration` in the extracted module and provide the scan path for the module.

```
@Configuration
// add any packages where you have bean definitions here (ex: ExtractedClass package)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class ExtractedConfig {

    // ...

}
```

Then, in the module where you use the dependency, import the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(ExtractedConfig.class)
public class MainConfig {

    // ...

}
```

You did not have the issue before the refactoring since the extracted beans were in the scan path (and therefore eligible for autowiring). When you've moved them in a different module that is no longer the case and you need to adjust the scan path accordingly.

Comment: I tried this, with `@Configuration + @Import(ExternalClass.class)`
inside the class using the artifact.

Inside the artifact i used this in the class the other code uses:
`@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pack1.pack2.pack4.pack5.pack6")`

The class I use is inside pack6.

However, when I do this I get several errors in this fashion: "Error creating bean with name [...]

Did I implement your solution correctly?

Comment: You should define packages as `basePackages = {"com.pack1", "com.pack2", etc}`

Comment: pack1, pack2 might have been a poor representation on my side, I meant to rename/anonymize my packages e.g. org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException
where pack1 would be springframework.

All classes are inside pack6, where some classes are in sub-packages of pack6. Pack 1-5 just represents my "directory".

Comment: @ArneO.Ose Really, you should reduce your problem to an [mcve], as I already suggested in a comment on your question, and then post that complete code. Trying to "anonymize" things here on the fly and just talking on an abstract level about it will most likely not lead to substantial help.

Comment: I found where my problem was (I posted an answer). Also, I used `@SpringBootApplication`, which do not require `@ComponentScan` as this is already "inside" it. Doing both shows a _redundant_ error in Intellij. But thank you for your answer, it helped me in the right direction :)